# Values from drop down list that inserted in mysql are all the same

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that allow user to choose the quantity values in drop down list.
After I clicked the submit button, the values inserted in mysql. When I made an option again even though I chose different value, all the values were getting same which is the same value is 5. Why?
Here's the code

view.php

```
echo "<td align='center'>";
echo "<select name='kuantiti'>";
for($x = 0; $x<=$row['kuantiti']; $x++){
    echo "<option value='$row[kuantiti]'>$x</option>";
}
echo "</select></td>";
```

process.php

```
$kuantiti = $_POST['kuantiti'];

if (isset($_POST['pinjam'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_request 
                (nama, noic, 
                jawatan, peringkat, 
                peralatansukan, kuantiti) 
            values ('$_SESSION[nama]', '$_SESSION[$noic]',  
                    '$_SESSION[$jawatan]', '$_SESSION[$peringkat]', 
                    '$peralatansukan', '$kuantiti')";
```

I'm sorry if you not too understand with my statement. My english is not so good enough. Any other help/suggestion will greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Updated :
[Here's the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqJqp.jpg)
[Here's the mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TA4c.jpg)

In view.php

I choose 13.

In mysql, the value inserted as 5.

The maximum value is depend on admin page on what quantity that she wants to put in  updatequantity.php means she update the quantity and automatically the quantity updated in mysql. That's why I put the $row['kuantiti'] in the for loop.

Comment: so how can I change them tho?

Comment: Upto how many kuantiti can they select 0 to ?  You will have to put the maximum quantity number in $x<=MAXIMUM instead of $row['kuantiti']

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the variable from the loop to get a matching value for the numbers you show in the visible part of the dropdown

```
echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
// passed to PHP ----^^,,^^ What is shown to the user
// they do not necessarily have to be the same thing
```

Comment: I've changed them like that before, and the inserted values was 0 since I declared the $x=0 in for loop.See my code above again.

Comment: Do you mean you want to start from 1 and not zero?

Comment: no. I just want to start from 0. Is that related in the value problem sir?

Comment: What exactly is your value problem

Comment: my problem is, all the chosen quantity value in the drop down list was same in mysql after inserted.even I choose different quantity. the same value that inserted in the mysql  is 5.

Comment: But that wont happen now, as you are passing the proper values. Retest the script using this change

Comment: Please read my question again sir. I've updated it. Hope you can see the problem by seeing the image link.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same parameter in option value for all options, you need replace that for the same value that you are displaying:
In your view.php:

```
echo "<td align='center'>";
    echo "<select name='kuantiti'>";
    for($x = 0; $x<=$row['kuantiti']; $x++){
     echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
      }
    echo "</select></td>";
```

Comment: I've changed them like that before, and the inserted values was 0 since I declared the $x=0 in for loop.See my code above again

Answer (score -1):

If you want quantity to have option 0 to 10 in drop down you have to change view to

```
echo "<td align='center'>";
echo "<select name='kuantiti'>";
$maxKuantiti = 10;
for($x = 0; $x<=$maxKuantiti; $x++){
    echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
}
echo "</select></td>";
```

Hope this helps